# XPath Selector to get IMDB release Date

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am practicing using Xpath selectors, and it seems to be very difficult to extract the release date from this website. I can get to the div class='txt-block', but not past that. I am trying to the get the date underneath it. E.g. "18 July 2008 (USA)"

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/?ref_=adv_li_tt

I can get up to this part. But I cannot get the text below.

[Xpath screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUNC3.jpg)

Comment: Could you post what you have already tried as a starting point?

Comment: @chamilad as a starting point I have tried this: //h4[contains(., 'Release Date')]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use :

```
//a[contains(@title,'release')]/text()
```

or

```
//h4[contains(.,'Release')]/parent::*/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression to test in Chrome inspector:

```
$x(".//h4[contains(.,'Release')]/parent::*/text()[normalize-space()]")
```

[image]